# Mysql query countdown until date expiration

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

SELECT DATE_FORMAT( `expiry_date`, '%d.%m.%Y' ) FROM `my_subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = '[user_id]'

which extract expiry date of users subscription plan of my site. Now I would like use another query who count and extract remaining days before reach expiration date. I'm not a sql guru and have poor knowledge about. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(expiry_date,NOW()) AS days 
FROM my_subscriptions WHERE user_id = '[user_id]';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(expiry_date, CURDATE()) AS days_until_expire FROM my_subscriptions WHERE user_id = '[user_id]'
```